# IK elbows twist mesh Fk poles face bend the wrong way

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

Whenever I try pose my model using Ik_arms the arms bends the wrong way.And if I turn the pole controls on they bend the correct way but the mesh twists.How can I stop the mesh from twisting when using IK_Arms with the poles turned on Or how do I make sure the elbow faces the correct way when the poles are off

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: make sure that the Roll Angle is correct and that you have a Pole Target, if it's still not the problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/